# Mysql doesn't sort properly varchar column

Tags: mysql, sorting

I have a database table looking like this:

```
projects
- id (autoincrement)
- client_id (unsigned int)
- project_id (unsigned int)
- project_type (varchar)
- project_name (varchar)
- is_active (tinyint)
```

In my schema I've got different project types, each of them has it's own table, thats why the project_id and project_type are for. And a project is related to a client, a client has many projects. That being said, when I run a simple query like this:

```
select * from projects order by project_name asc
```

It doesn't return a sorted list of project from a-z like I would expect, instead it sort few results and 'resets' the sorting. To give an example, if I have 40 records in total, it sorts 35 from a-z then it starts again from a to z.

Example:

```
arrow
car
family
google
hitman
ant
zeus
```

Thats the kind of result I'm getting, it is indeed sorted, but by chunks, and I can't understand why.

Comment: What is the column's collation? Show the output from `SHOW CREATE TABLE projects`.  Are some of the values capitalized while others are not? Do the strings contain exactly what you think they contain (check with `LENGTH()` or is there whitespace or non-printables at the start of some?

Comment: Two words: leading space

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Bingo, I can't believe I didn't check that out earlier, thank you both.